# Azure - How to move a single proxmox VM to Azure

Tags: azure, migration, proxmox, azure-migrate

I'm currently migrating all our VM to Azure.

However, I wasn't able to migrate our proxmox VM to Azure. Could someone please teach me a method to do it please ?

Many thanks ! :)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> How to move a single proxmox VM to Azure

*Yes, you can convert Promox VM to Azure with the help of below command which you need to use in the directory where the VM is stored.*

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vpc disk.qcow2 disk.vhd
```

*Else you can even use the third-party application to convert Promox to Azure.*
Here is the link of the application, [StarWind hyper convergence](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConvertingtoMicrosoftAzure.html)

*You can check the Below links which has related discussions.*

1. *https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/convert-vm-to-vhd-azure.68850/*
2. *https://www.reddit.com/r/Proxmox/comments/hv7yrk/proxomox_server_to_azure_v/*